# Formatted the eMMC of Beaglebone black Rev A

Tags: beagleboneblack, beagleboard

I am using Beaglebone black Rev A.It was running with Debian OS.I was using that in console mode by configuring that with my windows laptop.Today to format my sd card I have accidentally formatted the Beaglebone eMMC. Now when I try to connect it with my laptop it is showing me driver not accepted some error messages.I am new to this.Please help me now how to recover it.

Answer (score 0):

See if below link helps,

http://www.element14.com/community/docs/DOC-67138/l/beaglebone-black-software-image-update-instruction

It has steps for micro SD card as well as eMMC.

Comment: What setup do you have? do you have FTDI cable ?

Comment: I made my BBB to connected to monitor,keyboard and mouse giving 5V power supply to it.After following all those steps I pressed the boot button and applied power to it.I didnt release the boot button for more than 1 minute.But the leds didnt flash.

Comment: Most probably your SD card is not flashed properly. Can you check what `boot` partition contains ? Before this problem, was monitor and keyboard setup working for you ? What kind of monitor are you using , HDMI ?

Comment: also refer this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/beagleboard/boot/D4VuhA6kwBI).

Comment: yes before this problem every thing went fine.I am using HDMI

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100964/discussion-between-ankurtank-and-sowmya-ravichandran).